# Как спарсить телефон CURL?

Tags: php

делаю себе парсер досок объявлений. Есть некоторые сложности с некоторыми сайтами, а именно с парсингом телефонов .

К примеру, есть объявление (сайт выбран произвольно)
https://market.kz/a/elektrokacheli-detskie-babyhit...
С этого сайта я делаю парсинг телефона таким образом

```
function get_page1($url,$data=null, $options=null)
  {
    $process = curl_init($url);


    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://market.kz/a/elektrokacheli-detskie-babyhit-best-rest-v-magazine-butuz-643679/'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);



    if(!is_null($data))
    {
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }
    if(!is_null($options))curl_setopt_array($process,$options);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookiefile.txt');
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookiefile.txt');
    //curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cok) ;
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5');
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    curl_close($process);
    //usleep(200);
    //sleep(rand(1,3));
    //parser_sleep();
    return $return;
  }

  $pp = get_page1('https://market.kz/ajax/load-phones/','id=643679');

  //preg_match('/\'phone\':\'%2B(\d+)\'/iU', $pp, $t);

  echo $pp;
```

- на других сайтах попроще, данный код работает как надо ! 
  Через файербаг вижу, что только id- объявления в POST-е передается, а сам скрипт не хочет парсить . 
  Не прошу сделать мне парсинг, а просто хочу услышать советы, которые мне бы помогли : может сессии какие-то или реферы у них проверяются, хеши или что еще .. 
  Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить заголовок

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Для проверки запросов можно использовать Postman или аналог